# How to access model variable in block class magento

Tags: magento-1.7, blocks, model

I am working on custom module.The code is written in following order:

```
class JG_Mymodule_Model_Mysql4_Mymodule{ }
```

One of my friend wirte code in model like that:

```
protected function _afterLoad(Mage_Core_Model_Abstract $object)
    {


        $select = $this->_getReadAdapter()->select()
            ->from($this->getTable('findyoursize_values'))
            ->where('findyoursize_id = ?', $object->getId());

        if ($data = $this->_getReadAdapter()->fetchAll($select)) {
            $storesArray = array();
            foreach ($data as $row) {
                $storesArray[] = $row['dimensions_id'];
            }
           $object->setData('in_products', $storesArray);
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setMyValue($storesArray);
        }

        return parent::_afterLoad($object);

    }.
```

I want to use `$object->setData('in_products')` value in my block class , how can I access that value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are *copying* (not referencing) the `in_products` property to the session instance, given that it's available on the object instance which you are `load()`ing.

I recommend to always pull this array from the model instance. `$object->getInProducts()` and `$object->getData('in_products')` are both acceptable.

Comment: I didn't get you point clearly.because this object can't be accessible in block class . is it ?.If you see at my question i use session for that but it is alternate way.I want to do it without session.Hope you got my point

Comment: In your block's `_prepareLayout()` method you can instantiate your model using e.g. `$model = Mage::getModel(/* class */)`, call `load(/* id */)` as you must currently be doing, and then assign the model instance to the block instance scope using `$this->setModel($model)`. You can then retrieve the model instance in the block or in the template using `$this->getModel()`.

Comment: Thanks i got my value like this  $vari =  Mage::getModel('findyoursize/findyoursize')->load($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'));
      print_r($vari->getData('in_products'));.I want to chat with you for one other little issue.i have also posted question for that.you can see it on link.[http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5795/not-saving-data-to-database-in-magento]