# Not saving data to database in magento

Tags: magento-1.7, mysql

Hi i write valid queries for data insertion but not successeded.If i print that query and excute it on sql server it works.I didn't figure out why this not works.
This is my table structure.

```
CREATE TABLE `findyoursizevalues` (        
                      `findyoursize_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,  
                      `key_val` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,     
                      `min_values` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,       
                      `max_values` int(10) DEFAULT NULL        
                    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1.
```

This is different queries i use for insertion but no output.

```
$connectionWrite = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
        $tableName = $connectionWrite->getTableName('findyoursizevalues');
        $connectionWrite->beginTransaction();
        $data = array();
        $data['findyoursize_id']= $fid;
        $data['key_val']=$key;
        $data['min_values']=$min_val;
        $data['max_values']=$max_val;

        $connectionWrite->query("insert into ".$tableName." values ('1','bbb','2','3')"); //query 1
        $connectionWrite->query(" insert into $tableName set findyoursize_id =$fid,key_val='".$key."',min_values=$min_val,
            max_values=$max_val ");// query 2
        $connectionWrite->insert($tableName, $data); // query 3
        $connectionWrite->commit();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just used following snippet in my model and sql installer and it worked fine.

```
/**
* @var $resource Mage_Core_Model_Resource
*/
$resource     = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$connection   = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
$table        = $resource->getTableName('some_table_name');

$query        = "INSERT INTO {$table} (`entity_id`,`entity_type_id`,`attribute_id`,`value`,`store_id`) VALUES ($entity_id, $entity_type_id, $attribute_id, $value, $store_id);";
$connection->multiQuery($query);
```

Comment: I am ruuning that code in helper but not works

Comment: I found the issue when i use single instance like $connectionWrite it not works but if i use seperate variables for connection  and write adapter then it works.As there any difference ?

Comment: I can't figure out whats your problem, please give your solution, how can you separated them.

Comment: when i use this type connection $resource     = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$connection   = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
.it works, but this type connection not work for me  $connectionWrite = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');

Comment: Strange behaviour, I don't know why? Check this one: $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource'); $connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');

Comment: yes this one works thats why i accept you answer.i am also figuring out why this happens.

Comment: Maybe if we use $resource=Mage::getSingleton('core/resource') Magento stores singleton to $resource variable and singleton  will be available during code execution time and it affects the result. Lets ask it from users like benmarks, vinai, Marius, philwinkle to clarify the situation.